# Why am I getting this error in the assembly code below?

Tags: assembly, masm64

This is my first trial running an assembly code for x64 in MASM:

```
_text SEGMENT
main PROC
    mov ah,0
    ret
main ENDP
_text ENDS
END
```

and I'm getting a linker error `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup`. Why?

I have the entry point `main` in Properties > Linker > Advanced > Entry Point

P.S.: the code assembles and executes as expected in x86.

Answer (score 2):

There's an entry point (_mainCRTStartup) within the C-Runtime library (CRT) **libcmt.lib**, which does some initialization tasks, and then hands off control to the entry point for your application *main*. You can change the default entry point, but usually you want the convenience of the initialization the CRT entry point does for you automatically.

There are two methods to avoid *LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup.*

1. Add libcmt.lib to the link command:
   (C-Runtime initialization calls *main*)

   ml64.exe test64.asm /link /DEBUG /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib **/defaultlib:libcmt.lib**
2. Specify the entry point main on the link command:
   (Avoids C-Runtime initialization and calls *main*)

   ml64.exe test64.asm /link /DEBUG /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib **/entry:main**

Here's some example MASM64 code to popup a window:

**test64.asm**

```
option casemap:none

externdef MessageBoxA : near
externdef ExitProcess : near

   .data
   
    szDlgTitle    db "MASM 64-bit",0
    szMsg         db "HELLO",0   

   .code

main proc
   ; Reserve 28h bytes of shadow space.
   sub  rsp, 28h       
   xor  r9d, r9d       
   lea  r8, szDlgTitle  
   lea  rdx, szMsg    
   xor  rcx, rcx       
   call MessageBoxA
   add  rsp, 28h

   ; rax contains the ExitCode from MessageBoxA(...)

   ; When the primary thread's entry-point function main returns,
   ; it returns to the C/C++ Runtime startup code,
   ; which properly cleans up all the C Runtime resources used by the process.
   ; 
   ; After the C Runtime resources have been freed,
   ; the C Runtime startup code explicitly calls ExitProcess,
   ; passing it the value returned from the entry-point function. 
   ; This explains why simply returning from the primary thread's entry-point function terminates the entire process.
   ; Note that any other threads running in the process terminate along with the process.

   ret
   
main endp

end
```

To build test64.exe, I use these batch commands:

**makeit64.bat**

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

ml64.exe test64.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib
```

The output is

[image: hello_masm]